# Display all Woocommerce orders under My Account

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to display all customer orders under my account queries to certain role. Tried using the following but only sorting out orders under the email.
How can I do that?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', 
'custom_my_orders_query' );
function custom_my_orders_query($args){

$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$args['post_status'] = array('wc-processing');
$args['meta_key'] = 'assignee';
$args['meta_value'] = $user_id;

return $args;
}
```